# Pandas to_csv() slow when writing to network drive

Tags: python, pandas

When writing to a Windows network drive with the Pandas `to_csv()` function the write operation is considerably slower than when writing to a local disk. This is obviously partly a function of network latency, but I find that if I were to write the data to a `StringIO` object and then write the `StringIO` object to the network drive it is considerably faster than calling `to_csv` directly with the network path, i.e.

```
from io import StringIO

# Slow
df.to_csv("/network/drive/test.csv")

# Fast
buf = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buf)
with open("/network/drive/test.csv", "w") as fh: fh.write(buf.getvalue())
```

I likewise find that when using the `fwrite()` function from the R `data.table` package there is a much smaller difference in write time between the local and network drives.

Given that I need to frequently write to a network disk I am considering making use of the "fast" method above using `StringIO`, but I am curious if there isn't some option I am overlooking in `to_csv()` that will get the same result?

Comment: Try adding `chunksize=65536` or even `chunksize=1024*1024` to `to_csv` (the slow one).

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to have any effect on the write speed.

Comment: maybe because `to_csv()` has to format data during saving and it may need to write in small chunks - but `StringIO` has all data already formatted as one string and it can write all as one chunk